# How can we group the list using c#?

Tags: c#

I need to find the number of test cases failed.Here  TC003 Contains (3 SUB testcases) in which 2 is passed and 1 is failed.

I need to get the count the total testcase(4) Passed:-(3) Failed-(1).How can I do this.

```
TC001-Passed
TC002-Passed
TC003-Passed
TC003-Passed
TC003-Failed
TC004-Passed
```

I have in a dataTable i.e. `ItemArray[0]` Contains TestCaseID and `ItemArray[3]` Contains Status

Comment: Are these arbitrary strings or are they inside a custom object?

Comment: I have in a dataTable ie.ItemArray[0] Contains TestCaseID and ItemArray[3] Contains Status

Comment: please give structure you are using then after we will able to help you out or say you are stuck in structure creation too

Comment: -1 cant make sense of the question..its incomplete

Comment: can you able to put some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is awkward, but let's be straightforward:

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> AllTheTestCasesStrings = new List<string>();
    AllTheTestCasesStrings.Add("TC001 Passed");
    AllTheTestCasesStrings.Add("TC002 Passed");
    AllTheTestCasesStrings.Add("TC003 Passed");
    AllTheTestCasesStrings.Add("TC003 Passed");
    AllTheTestCasesStrings.Add("TC003 Failed");
    AllTheTestCasesStrings.Add("TC004 Passed");

    List<TestCase> AllTheTestCases = new List<TestCase>();

    foreach(string CurrentTest in AllTheTestCasesStrings)
    {
        TestCase NewTest = new TestCase();
        NewTest.Name = CurrentTest.Split(' ')[0];
        NewTest.Passed = CurrentTest.Split(' ')[1].Equals("Passed");

        AllTheTestCases.Add(NewTest);
    }

    int FailedTestCases = AllTheTestCases.Where<TestCase>(x => !x.Passed).GroupBy<TestCase, string>(x => x.Name).Count();
    int PassedTestCases = AllTheTestCases.Where<TestCase>(x => x.Passed).GroupBy<TestCase, string>(x => x.Name).Count();

    Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + FailedTestCases);
    Console.WriteLine("Passed: " + PassedTestCases);
}

public class TestCase
{
    public string Name;
    public bool Passed;
}
```

Comment: The 3 test cases of id `TC003` should be grouped together.  You are going to return a result of 1 failed, 5 passed, which is incorrect.

Comment: @mellamokb Now I see, thanks for the feedback. I'm taking a look at it right now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have LINQ available, you could try a solution like this, where `dt` is your datatable having column index `0` as testcase-id (1, 2, 3, 4), and column index `3` as status (`Passed`, `Failed`):

```
var rows = dt.Select();
var results = rows.GroupBy (r => r[0])
    .Select (r => new {
        TestCaseID = r.Key,
        Status = r.Any (x => x[3].Equals("Failed")) ? "Failed" : "Passed"
    } );

var total = results.Count();
var passed = results.Count(r => r.Status == "Passed");
var failed = results.Count (r => r.Status == "Failed");

Console.WriteLine("Total Testcases: " + total);    // 4
Console.WriteLine("Passed: " + passed);            // 3
Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + failed);            // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have in a dataTable i.e. ItemArray[0] Contains TestCaseID and
>   ItemArray[3] Contains Status

Ok, here's an approach with a DataTable and `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
var tcaseGroups = tbl.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<String>("TestCaseID"))
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Testcase = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
        CaseInfo = g.GroupBy(r => r.Field<String>("Status"))
                     .Select(gStatus => new
                     {
                         Status = gStatus.Key,
                         Count = gStatus.Count()
                     })
    });

// output the result
foreach (var x in tcaseGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("Testcase:{0}, Count:{1} Results:[{2}]", x.Testcase, x.Count
        , String.Join(",", x.CaseInfo.Select(xx => 
            String.Format("Status:{0} Count:{1}", xx.Status, xx.Count))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq to group by ItemArray[0] and then count instances of ItemArray[1].

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            //table to mimik your structure
            var table = new List<string[]>(new[]
                {
                    new[] {"TC001", null, null, "Passed"},
                    new[] {"TC002", null, null, "Passed"},
                    new[] {"TC003", null, null, "Passed"},
                    new[] {"TC003", null, null, "Passed"},
                    new[] {"TC003", null, null, "Failed"},
                    new[] {"TC004", null, null, "Passed"}
                });

            //calculate
            var grouped = from itemArray in table
                          //group by the testid
                          group itemArray by itemArray[0]
                          into g select new
                              {
                                  TestCaseId = g.Key,
                                  //add up the passes and fails
                                  PassedCount = g.Count(i => i[3] == "Passed"),
                                  FailedCount = g.Count(i => i[3] == "Failed")
                              };

            //enumerate and output to screen
            foreach (var group in grouped)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TestCase {0} Passed: {1}, Failed: {2}",
                                  group.TestCaseId, group.PassedCount,
                                  group.FailedCount);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```